# is it possible to change the html title ( the_title ) after it's been populated by wp?

Tags: php, wordpress

You may find this weird, actually very weird, but is the following possible?

just load up a post or page into the admin panel and place something like
this into the TINYMCE editor;

```
[?php

//assuming exec-PHP is ready and enabled

$current_page_url_here = get_current_url();

echo "<a href='{$current_page_url_here}?var1=val1'>click me</a>";

if ( $_GET['var1']=='val1' )
{
  //change the current post's html title to <title>val1</title>
without using javascript/jquery
}

?]
```

so when the visitor, clicks on the "click me" link, the page reloads but
this time, the html title reads "val1".

Is such a thing technically possible? 
Or is it too late ( as I expect ) at that time to make a change into the already calculated the_title() function return value?

Could ob_start in any shape or form be deployed here to achieve this goal?

Since search engine aspect is important, I cannot take a JS/JQuery ( client side ) solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think it might be possible ... u will run the above if statement in header.php and assign the different titles depending on the results....take a look at twentyeleven wordpress theme header.php there they change the site description on what's being viewed.

Comment: That's a vey good answer... I will take it, but I just realized, I asked the question the wrong way. I need to formulate it again to ask what I actually want to do in a better way. In my question, I made it too simple; I was making the title string available in the QS. So, yes, one can read the title and create a hook into where the the_title is set and take it from there. But to make my case, I need to come up with a good example that is easy to understand and relate to then ask it again.